# Where is an array stored in memory in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, heap-memory, stack-memory

We know objects are stored in the heap area.

Suppose we are inside a function block where we declare:

```
var a=[1,2]
```

And

```
var b=new Array(1,2)
```

Will both the array objects be stored on the heap or will `a` have space in the stack area and will `b` be on the heap?

Comment: I'm curious: Why do you want to know?

Comment: This is up to the browser, and not of much interest to the JS developer. I am also curious why you're wanting to know.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no difference to where the array is stored whether you create it with an array initializer (aka "array literal", `[1, 2]`) or the `Array` constructor (`new Array(1, 2)`).

Re where the array is stored:

It's up to the JavaScript engine implementation, and so may vary from implementation to implementation.

Some advanced engines use *escape analysis* to determine where to allocate objects, including arrays, which means they may be allocated on the stack or may be allocated on the heap depending on whether the engine sees that they are local to the function or they escape the function (e.g., by being returned, or assigned to a variable the function closes over, etc.).

---

Side note: There's almost never any reason to use `new Array`.

Comment: I have other thoughts on your statement of "..almost never any reason to use new Array". Yesterday I tried to build a 2-dimensional array with the 2nd dimension being uneven. I couldn't do it without using Array constructor and .push() to make it uneven. I have seen too many languages took away too much capabilities, considering of making it simpler, but they ended up crippling the entire language instead. IMHO

Comment: @xam T.J. might be telling use of `new` keyword?

Comment: @xam - Building an n-dimensional array isn't any easier using `new Array` than it is with array initializers. Examples: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/pjqgusc8/ (Side note: JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays. It has arrays of arrays.) HTH!

Comment: I spend some time to look into your example and found that wouldn't work the same as .push(), which requires Array construct. .push() allows me to add items blindly in an orderly fashion. While [] required of indexing and keeps track of where to add the item, to avoid empty slots or overwritten slots. But thank you for the nice example, @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @xam - `push` doesn't require the `Array` constructor: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/jnv1r5dh/ The array is exactly the same whether you create it with `[]` or `new Array()`.